# How do separate panes work in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm trying to create a strategy that includes 2 basic factors:

1. Creating a label that marks the second green bar to open above the 9 day SMA line on the chart as confirmation.
2. Having a separate RSI indicator in it's own pane below the chart.

I'm having trouble keeping the RSI and bar confirmation labelling separate, the chart labels seem to get dragged down into the RSI pane below.

Also, Once I deleted the RSI code, the bar confirmation chart labels remained in the below pane where the RSI was.

Below is the code to mark the second green bar to open above the SMA, how do I get it out of the separate pane?

---

```
strategy(title="Swing Strat", overlay=false, pyramiding=1, default_qty_value=2,   default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, initial_capital=10000, currency=currency.USD)


//Plotting MA

MAPeriod9 = input(9, title="9 MA Period")
MA9 = sma(close, MAPeriod9)
MAPeriod180 = input(180, title="180 MA Period")
MA180 = sma(close, MAPeriod180)

plot(MA9, color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(MA180, color=color.red, linewidth=1)

//checking to see if there are 2 bars above the sma line

MAcrossover = crossover(close, MA9)
entrypoint = barssince(MAcrossover)

//marking the second green bar to open above the SMA line
if entrypoint==1 and MA9<open and open<close and open[1]<close[1]
    lun1 = label.new(bar_index, open, 'entrypoint', 
      color=color.red, 
      textcolor=color.red,
      style=label.style_xcross, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment an indicator/strategy can either be on the main pane (with `overlay=true` as the argument in the `study()` or `strategy()`) or on its own new pane (by default or with `overlay=false`). There is no way to have one plot on a separate pane while also having other plots/labels on the main one if you are only using one script.

The only exception to this are the position arrows that the strategy itself creates - they always appear on the main pane, but that is hardcoded.

Comment: I see, so my strategy is based off 2 conditions:  
1. The second consecutive bar to open above 9 day SMA in green  
2. The RSI must be between 30-40.  
So what you're saying is that I'd need to have the overlay set to false to code the RSI in on a separate pane, and then hardcode the arrow labels to mark the 2nd bar to open above 9 day SMA as confirmation?